# Auto rotate custom drawn view on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have a UITableView full of custom draw cells. When the view rotates, it just stretches all my custom drawing. How can I get my views to redraw themselves when the view rotates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your views' `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeRedraw`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to override like **willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:** so:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Of coarse, this only works in 3.0 and you would need to reload all of your sections if you had more than one.